# splitting hours and minutes from a duration column in R

Tags: r

In my dataset have a column named duration. From it I want to split the hours and minutes into 2 separate columns. If either hours or minutes is not there want to add 0h or 0m accordingly.

Provided the same existing column details as well as the expected new columns in the below attached image:

```
train <- read.csv("sampledata.csv", stringsAsFactors = F)
train$Duration
```

[image]

Edit:

```
sampledata <- data.frame(
   emp_id = c (1:5), 
   Duration = c("10h 50m","5h 34m","9h","4h 15m","23m"),
   stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

sampledata$Duration
```

Comment: Why is this question getting down voted? Would people have some courtesy to point out the mistake

Comment: Please edit the question as stated here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Downvoted for data as image and no effort to solve the problem. You can try to use `lubridate` package and ask others to help you when you have an actual code.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. Attached as image because wasn't aware how to display as text in table format here. I had it in csv file one column but didn't find a way to attach the csv file as part of the question. No worries thanks for your time!!

Comment: would you always have only hours and minutes in the `Duration` ? Could it be seconds or something else ? Also do you need `h` and `m` in the final column or just numbers would do since your column already has names `hours` and `minutes` ?

Comment: @RonakShah that column would always have only hours and minutes. Yeah you are right in the final column numbers alone should suffice.

Comment: Hey did you accidentally downvoted my below answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the best of answer I would say but one way would be

```
#Get numbers next to hours and minutes
hour_minute <- sub("(\\d+)h (\\d+)m", "\\1-\\2", sampledata$Duration)

sampledata[c("hour", "minutes")] <- t(sapply(strsplit(hour_minute, "-"), 
function(x) {
  if (length(x) == 2) x 
  else if (endsWith(x, "h")) c(sub("h", "", x), 0)
  else c(0, sub("m", "", x))
}))

sampledata
  emp_id Duration hour minutes
1      1  10h 50m   10      50
2      2   5h 34m    5      34
3      3       9h    9       0
4      4   4h 15m    4      15
5      5      23m    0      23
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution using sub() and gsub would be like this

```
# first identify strings with "h"
h_in_str <- grepl("h", sampledata$Duration)
# if string has "h", then return all before "h" or else return 0
sampledata$Hours <- ifelse(h_in_str, sub("h.*", "", sampledata$Duration), 0)

# identify strings with "m"
m_in_str <- grepl("m", sampledata$Duration)
# if string has "m", return all numbers without those preceding "h" or else return 0
sampledata$Minutes <- ifelse(m_in_str, 
gsub("([0-9]+).*$", "\\1", sub(".*h", "", sampledata$Duration)), 0)
```

This gives you the data you are looking for

```
sampledata
emp_id Duration Hours Minutes
1      1  10h 50m   10      50
2      2   5h 34m    5      34
3      3       9h    9       0
4      4   4h 15m    4      15
5      5      23m    0      23
```